# Одинаков ли смысл

Tags: смысл

Скажите, поменялся смысл или нет во втором предложении? И можно ли говорить, что во втором предложении речь идет о баллончиках, которые предназначены для занятия спортом и охотой? Спасибо.

> К гражданскому оружию относится оружие, предназначенное для использования гражданами в целях самообороны, для занятий спортом и охоты.
>   Газовые баллончики, принадлежащие В. Т., являются гражданским оружием, предназначенным для использования гражданами в целях самообороны, для занятия спортом, охоты.

Comment: А что такое В.Т.? Расшифруйте, пожалуйста, без комментария вопрос не понятен.

Answer (score 1):

Однородные члены- перечисление целей использования.Между ними можно поставить как соединительные союзы(и), так и разделительные(или).В первом предложении значение включения(это всё гражданское оружие), значит, союзы И, во втором речь идёт именно о газовых баллончиках, у них цель только самооборона, следовательно, значение выбора, возможен союз ИЛИ.

Получается, ошибки нет, но в юридических документах это считается погрешностью, там не должно быть неясностей, разночтений. Гораздо яснее была бы фраза " В.Т. использовал газовые баллончики, ему принадлежащие,в целях самообороны,следовательно, они являются  гражданским оружием".К сожалению, не все юристы у нас грамотны. Фраза неказиста, зато использует обороты исходного документа, потому не может быть отвергнута как неверная.Но это может быть материалом для юмористов, как в этом случае.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Определение гражданского оружия

«К гражданскому оружию относится оружие, предназначенное для использования гражданами в целях самообороны, для занятий спортом и охоты».

(2) «Газовые баллончики, принадлежащие В.Т. является гражданским оружием, предназначенное для использования гражданами в целях самообороны, для занятия спортом, охоты.

Утверждение неверное, так как газовые баллончики - это частный вид гражданского оружия, предназначенного для самообороны, а здесь ему приписывается общее назначение гражданского оружия.